# If $\Bbb EN\in O(1)$ and $\Bbb ET_{i,n}\in O(t_n)$, can we conclude $\Bbb E\sum_{i=1}^N T_{i,n} \in O(t_n)$?

Tags: probability, algorithms, expected-value

Suppose for each $n\in \Bbb N$ that $N_n$ is a random variable with values in $\Bbb N$, and $(T_{i,n})_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence over the index $i$ of i.i.d. positive random variables.

> **Question:** If $\Bbb EN_n\in O(1)$ and $\Bbb ET_{i,n}\in O(t_n)$, can we conclude $\Bbb E\sum_{i=1}^N T_{i,n} \in O(t_n)$?

(You can think of $n$ as the input size to an algorithm, and we're taking the big-oh as $n\to\infty$. More context on this below). This is a lot like [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation), but without indepence between $N$ and the $T$'s, I don't know if we can do the above.

---

**Context:** On an old exam question I had several years back, we were considering a randomized algorithm on input size $n$, with expected running time $\le t_n$ and expected space usage $\le s_n$. We were asked to design an alogrithm with worst case space usage $O(s_n)$ and expected run time $O(t_n)$. The following hint was given:

> Hint: Restart the algorithm as neccesary. Note that there are two obvious choices for when to restart that both work, but one is much easier to analyze than the other.

My solution was to restart the algorithm of the space usage ever exceeded $ks_n$ **or** if the time usage ever exceeded $kt_n$, for some $k>2$. A pretty easy calculation then shows that $\Bbb EN \le \frac 1{1-2/k}\in O(1)$, where $N$ is the number of iterations of the algorithm, from which it follows that the expected total time is $\le kt_n \cdot\Bbb EN \in O(t_n)$.

But looking back, I'm now wondering what the other solution alluded to was. The other obvious choice to me, would be simply restarting the algorithm if the space used exceeds $ks_n$ for some constant $k$. Using a Markov inquality on the probability of restarting now leeds to $\Bbb EN \le \frac 1{1-1/k}\in O(1)$. Now, let $T_n$ be the total time of the algorithm, let $T'_{i,n}$ be the time used on each of iteration, and let $T_{i,n}$ be the time we *would have* used if we did not restart the algorithm. Then we get
$$
\Bbb ET = \Bbb E\sum_{i=1}^NT'_{i,n} \le \Bbb E\sum_{i=1}^NT_{i,n}.
$$
So the big question is, do we have $\Bbb E\sum_{i=1}^NT_{i,n}\in O(\Bbb ET_{i,n})$ or not? Note that $N$ is a stopping time for the space usage random variable, but not for $T_{i,n}$, so I don't think Wald's equation applies directly. We may use that time usage is always greater than space usage in an algorithm, if that somehow helps. Otherwise, I'm maybe hoping for an inequality version of Wald, something like
$$
\Bbb E\sum_i^N X_i \le C\cdot\Bbb EN \Bbb EX_i?
$$
Also,

> **Bonus question:** If this approach actually doesn't work, what would be the second "obvious" (but hard) solution that the exam givers allude to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a bunch of structure beyond the raw $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i \le n} T_{i,n}]$, since presumably

1. each time you restart the algorithm, you draw new coins for the new run.
2. the expected run time and space are bounded by $(t_n, s_n)$ uniformly over all instances of size $n$ (i.e., the expectation is only over the coins of the algorithm).

If so, then the details of the instance don't matter due to 2., and  all of the $(T_{i,n}, S_{i,n})$ are independent due to 1., which
simplifies things a lot.

Let me first clean up some notation - the $n$ is really not all that important for the problem, and neither is the details about the $S$s. So suppose $\{(U_i, V_i)\}$ is an infinite iid sequence from some law, where $V_i \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p)$. Let $N := \inf\{i: V_i = 1\}$. We are interested in the behaviour of $S_N := \sum U_i \mathbf{1}\{i \le N\}.$

With the above structure, it is straightforward to figure out the law of $(U_1, \dots, U_m)$ given $N = m$ (i'll work with pmfs, but densities work the same way). Indeed, $\{N = m\} = \{V_1^{m-1} = 0, V_m = 1\},$ and so, exploiting independence

$$ P(U_1^m = u_1^m, N = m) = \prod_{i < m} P(U_i = u_i, V_i = 0) \cdot P(U_m = u_m, V_m = 1)\\ P(N = m) = \prod_{i < m} P(V_i = 0) \cdot P(V_m = 1),$$ and thus $$ P(U_1^m = u_1^m|N = m) = \prod_{i < m} P(U_i = u_i|V_i = 0) \cdot P(U_m = u_m|V_m = 1).$$

Let $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ be the conditional mean of $U$ given $V = 0$ and $1$ respectively. Then by the above, $$ \mathbb{E}[ \sum_{i  = 1}^N U_i|N = m] = (m-1) \mu_0 + \mu_1,$$ and applying the tower rule $$ \mathbb{E}[S_n] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i = 1}^N U_i] = \sum P(N = m) ((m-1)\mu_0 + \mu_1) = (\mathbb{E}[N] -1) \mu_0 + \mu_1.$$

Now let $p = P(V = 1)$. Notice that $\mathbb{E}[N] = \frac{1}{p}$. Further, let $\mu = (1-p)\mu_0 + p\mu_1$ be the mean of $U$. Then we have $$ \mathbb{E}[S_N] = \frac{1-p}{p} \mu_0 + \mu_1 = \frac{1}{p} \mu.$$

Finally lets come back to the algorithm. Let $(T_i, S_i)$ represent an iid sequence of the runtimes on a given instance, where we draw new random coins for each run. Let $V_i$ be $0$ if the algorithm concludes before time $T_i$ due to using too much space, and $1$ otherwise. Let $U_i = T_i',$ the stoppage time of the ith run. Note that since for every $i$, $T_i' \le T_i,$ the mean of the $T'$s is bounded by that of the $T$s. Now running the above gives exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. So I see it turns out Wald's equation does hold in this case, as I had hoped. I have a couple of questions: 1. I didn't quite see the significance of calculating the joint probabilities of $P(U_1^m=u_1^m\mid N=m)$. Is it correct that we could also just use the marginal probabilities $P(U_i=u_i\mid N=m)$ and the expand $\Bbb E\left[S_N \mid N=m\right] = E\left[S_m \mid N=m\right] = \sum_i E\left[U_i \mid N=m\right]$ by linearity?

Comment: 2. Do you know if this falls into a usual case where we know Wald's equality should hold? It seems like the magic property was that we had the i.i.d sequence $(U_i, V_i)_i$ with $N$ being a stopping time for the $V_i$.

Comment: 3. And lastly a small comment: Shouldn't it be $U_i  = T_i$ in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Milten Re. 1,2, I think I was just going from first principles above. In general, a Wald-type identity holds whenever $N$ is a stopping time. Concretely, if the data is $\{X_i\},$ then $N$ is a stopping time if the event $\{N \le n\}$ is determined by $X_1^n$ (think of $N$ as a halting time for a procedure driven by the data stream. Then $N$ is a stopping time if the halting decision at time $n$ is causal, i.e., not dependent on the future $X_{n+1}^\infty$. Note that $\mathbb{E}[S_N] = \sum \mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbf{1}\{N \ge i\}]$. Now, using the tower rule and $\{N \ge i\} = \{N \le i-1\}^c$,

Comment: (contd) we can see that $$ \mathbb{E}[S_N] = \sum_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[ X_i \mathbf{1}\{N \ge i\}|X_1^{i-1}] ]= \sum_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{E}[ \mathbf{1}\{N \ge i\} \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_i|X_1^{i-1}]].$$ Now, if the $\mathbb{E}[X_i|X_1^{i-1}]$ were all the constant $\mu$ (as happens for iid processes), then this resolves exactly to $\mu \sum_{i \ge 1} P(N \ge i) = \mu \mathbb{E}[N]$. You can find more details in any text on stochastic processes or martingale theory - Williams' probability with martingales is a nice option.

Comment: In the above case, of course, $N$ is a stopping time since it is determined by the first nonzero $V_i$. And of course the $U_i$ are iid so we can directly get the statement (of course, I think w/o being exposed to the stopping time idea it would be very hard indeed to come up with this, I think the answer is more plausible as the intended approach).

Re. 3, I think $T'$ is more appropriate if you're studying the runtime of the algorithm? Of course, we any bound using $T_i' \le T_i,$ so you can use $T_i$ instead, this just moves the inequality slightly further up in the argument.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments! And sorry for the late reply. So there's just the final connection that I wanna make sure I understand. In order for your derivation be directly applicable, we should have $X_i = U_i$ (since $S_N = \sum U_i$). So we need $N$ to be a stopping time for $(U_i)_i$? I originally didn't think we could say that, since $U$ sequence by itself doesn't determine $N$. But if we just need $\{N\le n\}$ to be independent from $U_{n+1}^\infty$ (which it maybe, maybe not sounds like you're saying?), then $N$ is indeed easily seen to be a stopping time for $U$

Comment: (cont.) So basically, I'm either asking: Is $N$ indeed a stopping time for $U$? And if not, how do we apply your little theorem with the single sequence $X$ to our two-valued sequence $(U,V)$?

Comment: Good question. First observe that we can run the same argument to deal with functions of $X_i$ in the sum, i.e., work with $S'_N = \sum f(X_i)$, and argue that $ \mathbb{E}[ f(X_i)\mathbf{1}\{N \ge i\}|X_1^{i-1}] = \mathbf{1}\{N \ge i\} \mathbb{E}[f(X_i)|X_1^{i-1}]$ if $N$ is a stopping time with respect to $\{X_t\}$ (here the language of filtrations is a good way to concretise this, but you'll have to do some reading :)). Now take $X_i = (U_i, V_i)$ and $f(X_i) = U_i$. It's clear that $N$ is a stopping time w.r.t. this choice (because it's determined by a prefix of the $V$s).

Comment: To get slightly technical: the nub of the matter is that you can use any filtration $\{\mathcal{G}_t\}$ you like such that $N$ is a $\mathcal{G}$ stopping time and conditional expectations of the term in the sum is easy to nail down w.r.t. each $\mathcal{G}_t$. This actually has some subtle statistical consequences (but would be waaay off topic).  BTW from your questions I think you'll enjoy reading some of this in more detail, do check out the book I mentioned if you have time.

Comment: Thank you very much, that made the last penny drop! I really should have seen that myself haha, guess I'm a bit rusty. And sure, I just might pick up a book about this stuff